# Maximum number of nested conditions allowed

Tags: nested

Does anyone knows the limit of nested conditions (I mean conditions under another, several times)? In, let's say, Java and Visual Basic.

I remembered when I was beginning with my developing trace, I make, I think 3 nested conditions in VB 6, and the compiler, just didn't enter the third one, now that I remember I never, knew the maximun nested coditions a language can take.

Comment: What do you mean by nested condition? Nested `if` blocks?

Comment: Based on someone's java code I've been reading today, my headache and I can assure you, the limit is much higher than three.

Comment: It's just an example, and i also mentioned that it was a long time ago, i remembered that machine had like half gb or ram, assuming that it has something to with it

Comment: vb6 allowed you go way deeper than 3 nested blocks

Comment: for PHP, unlimited nested limit too, but some frameworks like Zend or xdebug put limit to 100 levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No limit should exist for a REAL programming language.  For VB.NET and Java I would be shocked if there is any limit.  The limit would NOT be memory, because we are talking about COMPILE TIME constraints, not executing environment constraints.

This works just find in C#:  It should be noted that the compiler might optimize this to not even use the IFs.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (true)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            if (true)
            {
                if (true)
                {
                    if (true)
                    {
                        if (true)
                        {
                            if (true)
                            {
                                if (true)
                                {
                                    if (true)
                                    {
                                        if (true)
                                        {
                                            if (true)
                                            {
                                                if (true)
                                                {
                                                    if (true)
                                                    {
                                                        if (true)
                                                        { Console.WriteLine("It works"); }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should not be optimized too much:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Month == 1)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Year == 2011)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Month == 1)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Year == 2011)
                {
                    if (DateTime.Now.Month == 1)
                    {
                        if (DateTime.Now.Year == 2011)
                        {
                            if (DateTime.Now.Month == 1)
                            {
                                if (DateTime.Now.Year == 2011)
                                {
                                    if (DateTime.Now.Month == 1)
                                    {
                                        if (DateTime.Now.Year == 2011)
                                        {
                                            if (DateTime.Now.Month == 1)
                                            {
                                                if (DateTime.Now.Year == 2011)
                                                {
                                                    if (DateTime.Now.Month == 1)
                                                    {
                                                        if (DateTime.Now.Year == 2011)
                                                        { Console.WriteLine("It works"); }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I'll take your answer, to the most accurate, maybe the only real way to find out, will be testing.

Comment: @Chuck did you finally test it? Because I find this interesting and it's quite a good thing to know. What did you find out?

Comment: @dominicbri7 Nope, sorry, haven't tried out yet, It was merely a curiosity. Maybe with a little of time, but there's probably a limit, in a quite some large series of conditions more elaborate, we'll probably see it

Comment: I know this is old, but can you clarify what is "REAL programming language"?

Comment: A non-fake one?  I was thinking of things like macro languages (terminal macros come to mind) and scripting languages that have limited capabilities.  I have met people who think recursion is when a statement is nested inside another... so perhaps any language written by those people as well.  Is my nose growing yet?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with most of the people here that there is no limit on writing the if blocks. **But there is a max limit on the java method size. I believe its 64K.**

Comment: I know this is old, but it's interesting. Source?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean nested `if` blocks then there is no theoretical limit. The only bound is the available disk space to store the source code and/or compiled code. There may also be a runtime limit if each block generates a new stack frame, but again that is just a memory limit.

The only explanation for your empirical result of 3 is either an error in programming or an error in interpreting the results.

Answer (score 0):

I must agree that the limit is purely based on memory limit. If you reached it, I would expect that you would reach some kind of stack overflow limit, however I doubt there is a possibility that you would reach this limit.

I could not find a source of reference to back this up, but a quick test of 40+ nested if statements compiled and ran fine.

Comment: I dont agree, you are answering the question of "What would be the limiting factor of how many nested conditions could a computer execute", not "how many does a language support in the compiler"

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Which is why I compiled and ran the test, and my answer said the limit would be based on a stack overflow, which would be machine specific, and not compiler specific.

Answer (score 0):

The limit to the number of nested conditionals will almost certainly be based upon the size of the compiler's stack and data structures, and not anything to do with the run-time environment except possibly in cases where the code space of the target environment is severely constrained relative to the memory available to the compiler (e.g. using a modern PC to compile a program for a small microcontroller with 512 bytes of flash).  Note that no RAM (beyond any used to store the code itself) is required at run-time to evaluate a deeply-nested combination of logical operators, other than whatever would be required by the most complex term thereof (i.e. memory required to compute '(foo() || bar()) && boz()' is the largest of the memory required to compute foo(), bar(), or boz()).

In practical terms, there is no way one would reach a limit using a modern compiler on a modern machine, unless one were writing a "program" for the specific purpose of exceeding it (I'd expect the limit would probably be between 1,000 and 1,000,000 levels of nesting, but even if it's "only" 1,000 there's no reason to nest things that deep).

Comment: Nested conditionals typically translate into code with some form of "goto".  The only factor limiting the number of nested conditionals is the compiler's ability to keep track of them.  At run-time there will generally not be a limit, except on a few languages like Postscript which use a run-time stack to manage nested conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Logically I would think that the limit would be based on the memory available to the application in Java.

Comment: And i must believe that such limit depends on the RAM, nice answer, but i'm looking something more concrete, like let's say 3 or 5, like just an example

Comment: @Chuck Birkin In order to provide you with a more concrete answer we would need to analyze the memory constraints on your machine and determine how much of the stack is devoted to other variables. Depending on how many other items are occupying space in your memory the number may fluctuate.

Comment: I dont agree, you are answering the question of "What would be the limiting factor of how many nested conditions could a computer execute", not "how many does a language support in the compiler"